# Inferences about a distribution given running maximum values

Tags: maximum-likelihood, quantiles, censoring

Here is a question inspired by [this question from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28172574/how-to-measure-latency-distribution).

Suppose you have observations of a variable which is measured once a minute, but the values are only recorded if they are greater than any that have come before, and thrown away otherwise. So at the end of a day, you have an increasing sequence of values, and, let's assume, the timestamps of those measurements. The problem is to make some statement about the distribution, such as some quantile.

Is this a recognized problem with a known solution? I'm assuming that this can be solved by treating the omitted measurements as censored data, as it is known that they are less than the most recently reported value.

Thanks for any comments.

Comment: Inference from record data. Hmm, I don't really know this stuff, but a couple of pointers - There's a 2003(?) book by Gurati and Padgett, (*Parametric and Nonparametric Inference from Record-Breaking Data*) which has a chapter on nonparametric inference; there are a number of papers on the topic, such as Samaniego & Whitaker (1988) "On Estimating Population Characteristics from Record Breaking Observations II. Nonparametric Results," *Naval Research Logistics Quarterly*. I don't know the recent research at all.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks for the references, I'll take a look. I've given two different approaches as answers to the SO question. If you are interested, perhaps you can take a look and tell me what you think.